# Scala Option.fold Behaves differently in and out of function

Tags: scala, option-type

Take the simple function:

```
def makeUpper(input: Option[String]): String = 
    input.fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }

makeUpper(Some("a"))   // A
makeUpper(None)        // b
```

This is as expected.

Now, the same code, but outside the function:

```
Some("a").fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }   // A
None.fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }        // error: value toUpperCase is not a member of Nothing
```

Note:

```
Option.empty[String].fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }   // b
```

**Questions:**

1. Why the different behavior? Why the error outside the function?

Is the function casting the input None to a "definitive" Option.empty[String]?

2. What is the correct way to handle returns from function that return Option (Some or None)... Do we always have to process the return value inside another function to avoid the above issue?

What am I missing?

Comment: The thing is that you should never have a value of type `None.type` or `Some` always `Option[X]` - If you know you have a `None` why even call `fold` if you know it will always call the `isEmpty` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala compiler can infer types.

Since you have defined the function parameter `input` as `Option[String]`, even if you pass `None`, the compiler knows that it is an `Option[String]` and appropritately types it.

Which is kind of doing this,

```scala
val none: Option[String] = None
none.fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }
```

Or this,

```scala
(None: Option[String]).fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }
```

When directly using `None` without any extra information, the compiler still tries to infer best guess useing only available information which is `None extends Option[Nothing]` and hence treats it as `Option[Nothing]`. Which is equivalent to,

```scala
val none: Option[Nothing] = None
none.fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }
```

or this,

```scala
(None: Option[Nothing]).fold("b"){ _.toUpperCase }
```

Notice that there is no indication of any relation to `String` in this case.

As long as you help the compiler by telling your intended type even at one place. It will be able to infer intended types for other relatable places.

```scala
scala> val noneIntOpt = noneStringOpt
// val noneIntOpt: Option[String] = None

scala> val noneIntOpt = noneStringOpt.map(_.length)
// val noneIntOpt: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: You can also use `Option.empty[String]`

Comment: Yes, but the question is only about `None`. This question is also linked to variance but I decided to answer without variance related details to keep things simple.

Answer (score 3):

`None` is defined as:

```
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

So when you call a method on the "contents" of `None` you are calling a method on a value of type `Nothing`. This type does not have a method `toUpperCase` so you get an error.

However `Nothing` is compatible with every type, and `Option` is covariant with its type parameter, so `Option[Nothing]` is compatible with `Option[String]`. This is why `None` can be passed to your `makeUpper` method. Once the type of the contents is known to be `String` the `toUpperCase` method can be called on it.